# Javascript - Auto click on a button on page load

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to auto click on a button with id btn on page load. This is my snippet.

```
<button id="btn">Click me</button>
<script>
document.getElementById('btn').click();
    alert("h")
</script>
```

How can I give an alert on page load? Pls help. Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```js
function test(){
   alert("Hi");
}

window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('btn').click();
  
var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
scriptTag.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="test()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, In this, the alert function is running way before my page is loaded.

Comment: place script at bottom of page or wrap an onload function?

Comment: @ReubenRodriguez updated!.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also pls tell how can I trigger another js on page load

Comment: did you mean load Javascript ?

Comment: @NishantDixit yes..

Comment: @ReubenRodriguez check now I am appending script tag in head on page load.

Answer (score 2):

Well the alert currently *is* happening on page load, because you haven't put it inside an event callback. You presumably meant:

```
//wait for DOM ready...
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

    //...get the button
    let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');

    //...bind the click event
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => { alert('hello'); }, false);

    //...trigger the click event on page enter
    btn.click();

}, false);
```

Note also the document ready handler, which waits for the DOM to be ready.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to give alert on page load than simply use this -

```js
window.onload = function(){alert("I am loaded")};
```

But if you want to give an alert after page load also by clicking on button use this -

```js
function autoClick(){
  alert("I am loaded and automatically clicked");
}
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('autoClickBtn').click();
}
```

```html
<button id="autoClickBtn" onclick="autoClick()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```js
   window.onload=function(){
      document.getElementById("btn").click();
      alert('Page Loaded')
    };
    function buttonClick(){
      alert("button was clicked");
     }
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="buttonClick()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Clicking the button will do nothing.

Comment: check the question plz before downvoting :-auto click on a button with id btn on page load.

Comment: He means the button should trigger the alert. In your code, the button does nothing.

Comment: yes call happens with button click but that happen with auto click not by manually

Comment: @Utkanos answer Updated